# Python Programming {Side Effects}

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this question I need help with. From what I assume, I'm missing something in `def main():`, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone assist me or provide the answer?

---

Write user-defined functions with these function headers:

```
def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    # Modify the argument list of integers by
    # appending a new integer that is the sum
    # of the last two integers in the list.
    # If the list has fewer than two elements
    # add the int object 1 to the list.

def main():
    # Call the append_fibonacci function on this
    # list: [3, 5, 8] and output the result object
```

Hint:

Use subscription to access the last two elements of the list and the `append` method to add a new element at the end.

The code I have looks like this:

```
def main():
    my_list = [3, 5, 8]
    append_fibonacci(my_list)

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    if len(integer_list) < 2:
        integer_list.append(1)
    else:
        integer_list.append(integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2])
    return integer_list
```

Error Outcome:

```
TEST 1
main() returned None
inputs:
outputs:
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * [3, 5, 8, 13]

----------
#TEST 2#
** ERROR **append_fibonacci(args) returned [10, 20, 30, 40, 70]
* EXPECTED * None
side effect from: [10, 20, 30, 40, 70] to: [10, 20, 30, 40, 70]
inputs:
outputs:

----------
#TEST 3#
** ERROR **append_fibonacci(args) returned [1]
* EXPECTED * None
side effect from: [1] to: [1]
inputs:
outputs:

----------
#TEST 4#
** ERROR **append_fibonacci(args) returned [15, 1]
* EXPECTED * None
side effect from: [15, 1] to: [15, 1]
inputs:
outputs:

----------
#TEST 5#
** ERROR **append_fibonacci(args) returned [-5, 8, 3]
* EXPECTED * None
side effect from: [-5, 8, 3] to: [-5, 8, 3]
inputs:
outputs:

----------
```

Comment: Your `append_fibonacci` function should not explicitly return anything. All it should do is modify the `integer_list` parameter as a side-effect, so simply remove `return integer_list`. Also, when the instructions say `If the list has fewer than two elements, add the int object 1 to the list`, I'm not sure they mean "append 1 to the list", I think they may want you to insert `1` at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Also from the first test error report, main should return my_list.  Currently, it's returning None (default return value when nothing is specified).

Comment: You missed a part: "and output the result object"

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to use the global keyword to achieve what you need and not return anything from append_fibonacci instead store the integer_list to my_list. You also need to print my_list from the main function.
Here is what I think:

```
def main():
    global my_list
    my_list = [3, 5, 8]
    append_fibonacci(my_list)
    print( my_list)

def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
    if len(integer_list) < 2:
        integer_list.append(1)
    else:
        integer_list.append(integer_list[-1] + integer_list[-2])
    my_list=integer_list
```

Comment: Test 2 to Test 5 didn't encounter any errors, only Test 1.                                              
(( #TEST 1#
** ERROR **main() returned [3, 5, 8, 13]
* EXPECTED * None
inputs:

outputs:
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * [3, 5, 8, 13] ))

Comment: it's close though.

Comment: you need to print from main not return from it. I have edited the code you can have a look at it.

Comment: you're the boss! It worked, you really helped me out cause I've been behind this question for 2 weeks. I was literally trying to figure out where the "return" statement should be, not knowing it was a "print" statement was required. Thank you vert much again

Comment: look at the inputs and outputs that's giving the error, if you read it properly you will know if its expecting a print or a return. Anyways, Happy to help